# iframe web page using csp: frame-ancestor

Tags: google-chrome, express, iframe, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I am using **express(lusca)** to add security headers but still not able to render my webpage inside jsbin/codepen/jsfiddle/localhost in **chrome**, and strange fact is it works in **IE** even without the headers.

The reason I am using **csp's frame-ancestor** is because I heard that **x-frame-options** is obsolete and doesn't allow multiple trusted hosts and wildcards.

Please suggest someway arounds.
I just want my app to be **iframed** only from some particular hosts.

```
app.use(lusca({
        csp: {
            policy: {
                'frame-ancestors': 'http://*.jsbin.com',
            },
        }
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a specific URL, you dont need the wildcard.
1)The following should work if your embedding URL is "https://output.jsbin.com/xyzcv/1/?html,output"

```
app.use(lusca({
    csp: {
        policy: {
            'frame-ancestors': 'https://jsbin.com',
        },
    }
}));
```

2) if your url is like "https://es.mydomain.com/page1" and or "https://fr.mydomain.com/page1" then you may use the wildcard

```
app.use(lusca({
    csp: {
        policy: {
            'frame-ancestors': 'https://*.mydomain.com',
        },
    }
}));
```